# Wikipedia Viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5

This is one of the projects on freecodecamp. I would like a review on my code. Thanks in advance.

***Javascript:***

```
var answers;

function formatSearchString() {

  var searchString = document.getElementById("searchBar").value;
  var words = searchString.split(" ");
  searchString = words.join("_");
  return searchString;

}

function getQueryData() {

  var stringToSearch = formatSearchString();
  var wikiUrl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + stringToSearch + "&format=json&callback=wikiCallbackFunction";

  $.ajax(wikiUrl, {

    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(wikiResponse) {
      //alert(wikiResponse);
      //alert(wikiResponse.length); Always 4.
      //alert(wikiResponse[0]); Search String
      //alert(wikiResponse[1]); Titles
      //alert(wikiResponse[2]); Explanations
      //alert(wikiResponse[3]); Links
      answers = wikiResponse;

    }

  });

  setTimeout(formatResults, 1500);

}

function getRandomArticle() {

  var wikiUrl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random";
  window.location = wikiUrl;

}

function formatResults() {

  $("#results").empty();

  var i = 0;
  for (; i < answers[1].length; i++) {

    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = "searchResults";

    var titleLink = document.createElement("a");
    titleLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    titleLink.setAttribute("href", answers[3][i]);
    titleLink.innerHTML = answers[1][i];

    var desc = document.createTextNode(answers[2][i]);
    var newLine = document.createElement("br");

    newDiv.appendChild(titleLink);
    var newLine = document.createElement("br");
    newDiv.appendChild(newLine);
    var newLine = document.createElement("br");
    newDiv.appendChild(newLine);
    newDiv.appendChild(desc);
    var newLine = document.createElement("br");
    newDiv.appendChild(newLine);

    var newLine = document.createElement("br");
    newDiv.appendChild(newLine);

    document.getElementById("results").appendChild(newDiv);

  }

}

document.getElementById("buttonForSearch").addEventListener("click", getQueryData);
document.getElementById("searchBar").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {

  if (e.which == 13) {

    e.preventDefault();
    getQueryData();

  }

  return false;

});

document.getElementById("randomArticle").addEventListener("click", getRandomArticle);
```

***CSS:***

```
 body {
      background: radial-gradient(circle, black, white);
      height: 700px;
      background-size: cover;
      text-align: center;
    }

#searchBar {
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 25px;
}

a {
  font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 45px;
}

#results {
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 550px;
}

.searchResults {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: auto;
  width: 650px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#buttonForSearch {
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  size: 14px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

#randomArticle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  size: 14px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
}

#searchFields {
  margin: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">

<body>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
  </script>

  <script src='http://okfnlabs.org/wikipediajs/wikipedia.js'></script>
  <h1>Wikipedia Search</h1>

  <div id="searchFields">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type To Search" id="searchBar">
    <input type="button" value="Search" id="buttonForSearch"><br /><br /><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Random Article" id="randomArticle">
  </div>

  <div id="results"></div>

</body>
```

Full Code Here:  http://codepen.io/jpninanjohn/pen/GZrzoG

Comment: Does it have a special reason why you declare the counting-variable that way : "var i = 0;
  for (; i < answers[1].length; i++) {" ? Instead of "for (var i = 0; i < answers.length, i++) {" ??

Comment: I first typed `var i=0;` with the idea of using a **while** loop. I then changed my mind to use a for loop. So I just used the already initialized variable `i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, it looks like you are trying to go around the async behaviour of AJAX:

```
$.ajax(wikiUrl, {

    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(wikiResponse) {
      //alert(wikiResponse);
      //alert(wikiResponse.length); Always 4.
      //alert(wikiResponse[0]); Search String
      //alert(wikiResponse[1]); Titles
      //alert(wikiResponse[2]); Explanations
      //alert(wikiResponse[3]); Links
      answers = wikiResponse;

    }

});

setTimeout(formatResults, 1500);
```

Whilst it does *work*, it could be better, because you're specifically saying 1500 milliseconds -- what if the request takes slightly longer?

Instead, use callbacks, like this:

```
$.ajax(wikiUrl, {
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: formatResults             
});
```

This will call the `formatResults` function when the AJAX request is successful, passing the `wikiResponse` as a parameter. You'd also need to add `answers` as a parameter to the function itself:

```
function formatResults(answers) {
    ...
}
```

and then you can get rid of your `var answers` at the top! :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the code is working. So congratulations there!

Some suggestions:

- Call formatResults in the success function itself. No need to manually call it later using setTimeout
- If you know jQuery, then do use it instead of native JavaScript code. Why let the library go in waste? Use it more, especially in formatResults function.
- Too fancy CSS. Preferably use Google fonts.
- Some code can be made more concise, like directly replacing the spaces with underscores, and doing away with writing a function for redirection (instead just write an anonymous function as the event handler). If you start using jQuery, event handling would become much more convenient.

That's it, I guess. Good job!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Just one doubt, when I call formatResults directly, I only get the answers on the second click. I assumed that's because the results are not ready immediately. Hence the timeout to obtain the results and then render it on the screen. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Exactly. That's why, to make sure that answers are ready, this function should be called as a callback function (success function in this case) to the Ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

One tip: group DOM reading and writing. It can speed it up. So instead of:

```
var a = document.createElement('div')
foo.appendChild(a)
var b = document.createElement('div')
foo.appendChild(b)
var c = document.createElement('div')
foo.appendChild(c)
document.getElementById('output').appendChild(foo)
```

you should do:

```
var output = document.getElementById('output')

var a = document.createElement('div')
var b = document.createElement('div')
var c = document.createElement('div')

foo.appendChild(a)
foo.appendChild(b)
foo.appendChild(c)
output.appendChild(foo)
```

Comment: By speed up, do you mean speed up the rendering of the elements on the page??

Comment: @leoOrion Yes, the browser's rendering.